# How can I use the membership payment table in searchkit?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, searchkit

I want to create a search using searchkit that identifies contributions (payments) with memberships, which are connected using the civicrm_membership_payment table.

I actually want to list the contributions of a type Membership Payment that are NOT connected to a membership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Contribution -> Left Join line items where entity_table = civicrm_membership

Where contribution FT= ABC and line_item.id IS NULL

[image]

Comment: 1. Are you saying I can add table joins in searchkit even if they're not listed or directly supported?
2. What do you mean by 'add a MembershipPayment file in Civi/API4' - are you talking about a custom extension? Or a PR?

Comment: I think core won't accept PR for MembershipPayment API4 as there was a discussion in past about deprecating the civicrm_membership_payment and participant_payment table over line_item. Going forward it will be via line item. You could implement that using custom extension. Or you could use line item table to joining to contribution

Comment: Yes, this is now almost the right answer. If you remove the 'add a file' suggestion and just have the picture and description of using the line item, then I'll accept as correct.

Comment: Done, i have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the API was missing to allow Contributions to join with Memberships.
Here is [a PR to add it](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29388), which allows you to do this in SearchKit:

[image]

Comment: Confirmed, that solves my need, thanks. I'd say that's a good sign for searchkit that it was that simple a PR.

Comment: Unfortunately that PR was rejected because the `civicrm_contribution_membership` table is being (sloooowly) phased out.

Comment: But fortunately, matt's comment set me on the one true path of enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

As per @mattwire's comment in @Coleman's PR, the Right Way to identify a membership payment is via the line item, when the entity_table is "civicrm_membership" and then the membership is the entity_id.

i.e. for my purposes: join the contribution table to the line items, and find contributions that have no civicrm_membership entries.